# How to check if class has variable and declare it in other class

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to check if another class has a member variable called "list" in it, and I want a `boolean` to tell me if that class has it or not.

If the class has "list", the `boolean` returns true and everything is good. But if the class DOESN'T have "list" in it, it doesn't return false but it causes an error:

```
public static void main(String[]args) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException{
    boolean has = Person.class.getDeclaredField("list")!=null;
    System.out.println(has);
}
```

The error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: list
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Unknown Source)
at test.main(test.java:21)
```

Line 21 is where I declared the boolean `has`.
So I have 2 questions:

1. How do I return false if there ISNT "list" in class Person?
2. If the varible exists, how can I make it into an object?

Answer (score 3):

> **How do I return false if there ISNT "list" in class Person?**

`Class.getDeclaredFields()` throws a `NoSuchFieldExeption` if the field does not exist, so you need to catch the `NoSuchFieldException`:

```
public static void main(String[]args) {
    boolean has = false;
    try {
       Person.class.getDeclaredField("list");
       has = true;
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException nsfe) {
       // intentionally ignored
    }
    System.out.println(has);
}
```

It is *usually* a bad idea to simply ignore a thrown exception (the `catch` block should at least contain something like `nsfe.printStackTrace()`), but in this case it should be fine.

> **If the varible exists, how can I make it into an object?**

I am not 100% sure what you mean by this, but you can get a **reference** to the desired attribute through the return value of [`getDeclaredField()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField%28java.lang.String%29), which is a [`java.lang.reflect.Field`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) - in that case, I would avoid the boolean and restructure the code slightly, e.g.:

```
// @param Person object which has a "list" member
public void printListField(Object p) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
  Field listField = null;
  try {
     listField = Person.class.getDeclaredField("list");
  } catch (NoSuchFieldException nsfe) {
     // intentionally ignored
  }

  if (listField != null) {
     Object l = listField.get(p);
     System.out.println("list is " + l);
  } else {
     System.out.println("No list member available!");
  }
}
```

Note that you need a reference to an actual object of class `Person` in order to retrieve a reference to an instance variable.

Comment: +1 for `// intentionally ignored`, which makes the code more maintainable.

Comment: I dont get it... What object should p be?

Answer (score 2):

As an answer to the first question, if there isn't such a list, the `NoSuchFieldException` is thrown, so catch that exception then and return or set a boolean to `false` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[]args) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException{
   try {
      boolean has = Person.class.getDeclaredField("list")!=null;
   } catch(NoSuchFieldException e) {
      has=false;
   }
   System.out.println(has);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So why not the below ?

```
try {
   has = Person.class.getDeclaredField("list")!=null;
}
catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
   has = false;
}
```

Although I can't help thinking your design is flawed such that you have to perform this check (if you're inheriting legacy code you may have little choice, perhaps)

Comment: Very very bad idea to catch every exception.

Comment: I would suggest it's a very very bad idea to do anything like the above regardless

Answer (score 0):

According to java-doc:

```
 * @exception NoSuchFieldException if a field with the specified name is
 *              not found.
```

So if you want to check that field exists you should intercept exception:

```
boolean has;
try {
    Person.class.getDeclaredField("list");
    has = true;
} catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    has = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all fields by reflection,then check each field from the field array.

Answer (score 0):

The method getDeclaredField will throw an exception(NoSuchFieldException) if the field does not exist.  So you have to put a try/catch block around this method.  And if you catch a NoSuchFieldException, then set has to false.

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
    boolean has = false;
    try {
        Field f = Person.class.getDeclaredField("list");
        has = true;
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        has = false;
    }
    System.out.println(has);
}
```

See the java documentation at the following link:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField(java.lang.String)